# values set in limits.conf are not working

Tags: linux, ulimit

I set some values in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as below:

```
*   hard    stack   204800
*   hard    nofile  8192
```

Then rebooted the server. Now the `ulimit` command still lists some old/default values:

```
# ulimit -s
10240
# ulimit -n
1024
```

I running `RHEL 6.2 64-bit`

What is wrong here? Is my syntax in `limits.conf` wrong? Why after server reboot it does not honor `limits.conf` values?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I was doing with `limits.conf` was correct and it was applicable. Just that I was running a wrong command to validate my changes. I am changing the `hard` limits, so the correct command should be `ulimit -Hs` and `ulimit -Hn`. Credit goes to  https://serverfault.com/a/556689/114516